# Print Questions with Code by Groups

Tags: listings, expl3, minted, exam, exsheets

I'd like to write a document with questions containing pieces of code (in `minted` environments), separated in two groups (say **A** and **B**, and with **A**∩**B** ≠ ∅), and their solution.
I'd like to be able to output (by changing the value of a switch, for instance):

- A document with the questions **A**,
- A document with the questions **B**,
- A document with the questions **A** and **B** and the solutions.

I tried with the `exam` class and the `exsheets` package, but couldn't find a simple solution.

**Is there any other alternative I am not aware of, or could one of my problem below be patched?**

### With the `exam` class

This class doest not offer the "print by group" feature.
There is a workaround, cf. https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/345651/34551, but it doesn't jive with the `minted` environment (`! FancyVerb Error`):

```
% !TeX TXS-program:compile = txs:///pdflatex/[--shell-escape]

\documentclass{exam}
\usepackage{minted}
\usepackage{xstring}% overkill


\newcommand{\SKey}{,,}% default

\newcommand{\selectkey}[1]% #1 = key to be used to select questions
{\xdef\SKey{,#1,}}

\newcommand{\selectquestion}[2]% #1 = comma delimited list of keys, #2 is the question (in braces)
{\IfStrEq{\SKey}{,,}{\question #2}{\IfSubStr{,#1,}{\SKey}{\question #2}{}}}

\begin{document}
\selectkey{2002}% only print questions with 2002 in list
\begin{questions}
\selectquestion{2002,1996}{
    \begin{minted}{csharp}
    int myAge;
    Console.WriteLine("Please enter your age:");
    \end{minted}
}
\selectquestion{1996}{This is question 2.}
\end{questions}

\end{document}
```

I guess there is a workaround by coming back to the "primitive" syntax, as exposed in https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/78688/34551 , but it seems cumbersome to carry out this construction for every question.

### With the `exsheets` package

`exsheet` provides a nice way of printing questions modularly, but isn't so good at dealing with code.
Since `exsheets-listings` was developed, there is a way to include code in `question` environments.
This solution has two strong limitations, in my opinion:

1. It uses the `listing` package (I know the debate is still ongoing at [minted vs. listings: pros and cons](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/389191/34551) , but I would like to stick with `minted`)
2. Including two pieces of code separated by some text is a nightmare. The `pre` and `post` options of the `lstquestions` allow some flexibility, but having in a question a pattern "Text / Code / Text / Code" is to my knowledge impossible.

Comment: You could use `xsim` instead of `exsheets`. In the past I have had no problems using it in combination with `minted` and the text flow you describe in (2).

Comment: Never heard of it: thanks, I'll look into it.

Comment: @TeXnician Thanks a lot for the pointer, `xsim` indeed does exactly what I wanted.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Turns out the `xsim` package does exactly what I wanted.

```
% !TeX TXS-program:compile = txs:///pdflatex/[--shell-escape]

\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{minted}
\usepackage{xsim}
\xsimsetup{
solution/print = true,
% tags = A,
tags = {A, B}
% tags = B
}

\begin{document}

\begin{exercise}[tags={A, B}]
\begin{minted}{csharp}
int a, b;
\end{minted}
\end{exercise}

\begin{solution}
    Yop
\end{solution}


\begin{exercise}[tags={B}]
\begin{minted}{csharp}
int b;
\end{minted}
\end{exercise}

\begin{solution}
    Yop
\end{solution}


\begin{exercise}[tags={A}]
\begin{minted}{csharp}
int a;
\end{minted}
\end{exercise}

\begin{solution}
    Yop
\end{solution}

\end{document}
```

By commenting out / un-commenting the

```
\xsimsetup{
solution/print = true,
% tags = A,
tags = {A, B}
% tags = B
}
```

I can achieve all the variations I was looking for, and keep using `minted`.